# How to set size of another window (a different application)?

Tags: java, window

Is it posible to set the size of another window created by a different program in java? For example, I'd like to change the size of a Google Chrome window (change from 1024*720 to 840*480)

Comment: yes, change the size of other window

Comment: Hello, it seems you should visit help center and learn [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).